Why is the git HEAD tag not annotated in a workflow?
Why does GitHub not get the pushed tag as annotated?
Locally if I run this command:
  git for-each-ref \
    --format="%(if:equals=tag)%(objecttype)%(then)a %(else)%(if:equals=blob)%(objecttype)%(then)b %(else)  %(end)%(end)%(align:20,right)%(refname:short)%09%(objectname:short)%(end)%09%(if:equals=tag)%(objecttype)%(then)@%(object) %(contents:subject)%(else)%(end)" \
    --sort=taggerdate \
    refs/tags \
  | tail -n2

I get:
a       v0.11.0 a385a1c @2c3ef8cdb5068e47f818af0c2bb81c5a6a2b2056 0.11.0
a       v0.11.1 55210a6 @9b389a86652517a49c025c40a2cd7bd614d3ace4 0.11.1

But on GitHub, when it runs the job on push of v0.11.1:
a       v0.10.0 b2e1fd0 @b746724eb7f2adbd254ebe66219d83fbad411326 0.10.0
a       v0.11.0 a385a1c @2c3ef8cdb5068e47f818af0c2bb81c5a6a2b2056 0.11.0

This is the actual job and the commit. This is the tag but it's likely to change what it points to.
Here's how I actually make release semver=0.11.1 || make rollback tag=v0.11.1:
.PHONY: release
release: pre-release gh-release

pre-release:
    $(call check_defined, semver)
    $(info Attempting to release $(semver))
    ./gradlew build --quiet
    git tag -m $(semver) -a v$(semver)
    ./gradlew assemble shadowJar --quiet
    ./gradlew publishPlugins --validate-only --no-configuration-cache --warn

gh-release: build/libs/*.jar
    $(call check_defined, semver)
    git push --tags

and a synopsis of the job:
name: Release
on:
  push:
    tags:
      - "v*.*.*"
jobs:
  publish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest  
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

So why is GitHub behaving differently than local git? Can I fix it?

I found this bug on the checkout action. This appears to be an acceptable workaround for my use case. There are a few other workarounds mentioned in that issue.
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          ref: ${{ github.ref }}

